# Solution file included in NuGet package incompatible with continuous build

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package

I found a NuGet package that contains sample of code and sln file. I would like to know if this is a common practice or if I should contact the owner of the package to tell him to remove these samples of his package.

The reason of my question is this created issues with my DevOps CI system. During continuous integration the system perform the package restoration then the build. By default build is set to **/*.sln. Then the build process also build all sln file inside the package restored.

Weird no? I never did any NuGet package so I don't know what are the rules and I would like to be sure of common practice before contacting the owner of this package.

Comment: My vote is - that's weird and he shouldn't include sample code in the NuGet package.

Comment: It really depends on what package you are referring to. Old packages (several years ago) might do that, but newer NuGet releases no longer recommend such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DevOps CI/CD system, you can specify the folder path (e.g. SampleDemo*.sln).

For the NuGet package, in general, it shouldn’t include code and sln files. Not sure whether the author want to include code and sln files or not. Maybe he wants others can custom his package easily and publish a new one.

So, you can confirm it with author.